# I'd like to know how I can store input from a semi colon separated text if some fields are missing

Tags: c, scanf

How can I skip scanf if some field is missing like between "oeb" and "7"?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int,a,b,c;
    char str1[200];
    char str2[200];
    char str[] ="1;2;oeb;;7;ed";
    scanf("%d;%d;%[^;];%d;%[^\n]",&a,&b,str1,&c,str2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You still have the `;`s separating values, right?

Comment: Are you obsessed with commas? Lol there is a comma after int in the declaration of a, b, c.

Comment: You really can't skip scanf after you've already called it!  You need to clarify the question.  Do you want to consider this an error?  or do you want to default to 0?  If you're going to use scanf (I would suggest you not do so), you could use scanf to parse each field into a string and then parse each string with strtol.  It would probably be easier to only scan one field at a time (again, that's *if* you're going to use scanf at all.)

Comment: `scanf` is unsuited for empty inputs. Maybe go lower-level, for example, `strchr` in a loop.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I dont want to consider it a error. I want to know how I can store the values I got even If I have empty fields. Not all fields are necessary to be present so I want to know how to "skip" those blank fields and read the ones with data.

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see the return value of scanf, it returns how many successful inputs have happened, you could check if all 5 have completed successfully, for example,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int,a,b,c;
    char str1[200];
    char str2[200];
    char str[] ="1;2;oeb;;7;ed";
    if (scanf("%d;%d;%[^;];%d;%[^\n]",&a,&b,str1,&c,str2) != 5) {
        // Error handling code here
    }
    else {
        // If everything is ok, continues here,
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I want to store the values I got even if it skips a field. Not all values are necessary to have so I don't need to accept it only if all fields are completed. I want to know how I can make scanf read what I have, be it 1,2,3 or all fields completed.

Comment: @CarlosGuimarães is this supposed to be on one line or multiple line inputs?

Comment: I'm getting lines from an outside file.

Comment: @CarlosGuimarães i don't think there is a easy way to do this, based on my knowledge, you should maybe prompt the user individual for each thing and if they enter blank strings then load a default value. That's the easiest solution I can think of, but I think you want to read the whole thing all at once.